# leafo/scssphp Ignoring files in sub-directories

Tags: php, sass, less, scss-mixins

leafo/scssphp works fine, except when the files are in the sub-directories, I tried addImportPath but still couldn't include those sub-directory files, here is my scss code.

```
.my-parent-container {
    background-color: $body-background;
    @import './base/reset';
    @import './abstracts/placeholders';
    @import './base/typography';
    @import './layout/header';
    @import './components/buttons';
    @import './components/switch_button';
}
```

PHP code

```
$scss = new \Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler();
$scss_path = base_path('public/assets/tmpl-scss/style.scss');
$scss->setVariables($colors);
$css = $scss->compile('@import "'.$scss_path.'"');
```

the files such as reset, placeholders, typography,header,buttons and switch_button are not added.

Thank you

Comment: you have a typo in the last line of CSS code. It should be @import './components/switch_button';

Comment: Sorry that was my copy paste and edit error, it doesn't work with @import './components/switch_button'; as well.

Comment: @MZH You have to use the `setImportPaths` method or the `addImportPath` one: https://scssphp.github.io/scssphp/docs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand in their documentation:
https://scssphp.github.io/scssphp/docs/

> When you import a file using the @import directive, the current path
>   of your PHP script is used as the search path by default. This is
>   often not what you want, so there are two methods for manipulating the
>   import path: addImportPath, and setImportPaths.
>
> addImportPath($path) will append $path to the list of the import paths
>   that are searched.
>
> setImportPaths($pathArray) will replace the entire import path with
>   $pathArray. The value of $pathArray will be converted to an array if
>   it isn’t one already.

So, I would do it like this:

```
$scss = new \Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler();
$scss_path = base_path('public/assets/tmpl-scss/style.scss');
$scss->setImportPaths([
    'public/assets/tmpl-scss/'
    'public/assets/tmpl-scss/base/',
    'public/assets/tmpl-scss/abstracts/',
    'public/assets/tmpl-scss/layout/',
    'public/assets/tmpl-scss/components/',
]);
$scss->setVariables($colors);
$css = $scss->compile('@import "'.$scss_path.'"');
```

And in the CSS:

```
.my-parent-container {
    background-color: $body-background;
}

@import 'reset';
@import 'placeholders';
@import 'typography';
@import 'header';
@import 'buttons';
@import 'switch_button';
```

Also, you might want to take a look at source maps: https://scssphp.github.io/scssphp/docs/#source-maps

I am not sure if this will work because I never personally used the Leafo ScssPhp. But you can try this and it might give you a starting point.

Comment: Sorry I tried that in all possible ways, but nothings works, here is the screenshot. https://imgur.com/PbIFhhR

Comment: did you also make the change in the scss file?

Comment: please check my answer and make sure you update the imports to what I did. Also, I did a change to the `setImportPaths()` method array

Comment: The real problem is when it is compiled, it doesn't include the file content, instead it just paste the import line, here is the compiled screenshot. https://imgur.com/9cwm08x

Comment: compiled to this  https://imgur.com/8KECPI9, not including the content of the files, instead it just put the url

Comment: why did you add the `@import` statements inside a class? move them outside otherwise it treats them as properties. Updated the answer now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203454/discussion-between-cornel-raiu-and-mzh).